# broadcast receiver never gets called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to learn how **Broadcast Receivers** work but I don't succeed, my receivers are never called. Can you guys point me in the right direction?

Here's the code:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OutgoingReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("com.javaGroup.broadcastReceiver.views.TEST");
    sendBroadcast(intent);

  }
}
```

**OutgoingReceiver.java**

```
public class OutgoingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  public static final String CUSTOM_INTENT = "com.javaGroup.broadcastReceiver.views.TEST";

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("HIT OUTGOING-----------------------------------","");
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction(CUSTOM_INTENT);
    context.sendBroadcast(i);
  }
}
```

**IncomingReceiver.java**

```
public class IncomingReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(OutgoingReceiver.CUSTOM_INTENT)) {
      Log.d("GOT THE INTENT-------------------------------","");
    }
  }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.javaGroup.broadcastReceiver.views" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>

   <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <activity android:name="com.javaGroup.broadcastReceiver.views.Main" android:label="@string/app_name">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
      </activity>

      <receiver android:name=".OutgoingReceiver" android:enabled="true">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
         </intent-filter>
      </receiver>

      <receiver android:name=".IncomingReceiver" android:enabled="true">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.javaGroup.broadcastReceiver.views.TEST"></action>
         </intent-filter>
      </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the right permission in Manifest for your receiver . See [list of permissions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

Comment: i have the phone state permission declared already... Look at the code above

Answer (score 0):

Of course you're not going to get it, your BCR (namely OutgoingReceiver) isn't registered to listen to that Intent (com.javaGroup.broadcastReceiver.views.TEST) which your Activity (Main) is broadcasting to.

### Note

You should write more comments in your code so that YOU can understand what you are doing. As it stands, I can only guess. You should understand the Activity lifecycle and the full behavior of what you are trying to do. By looking at your code, that's not exactly clear.